# Deploy Nodejs on multiple servers through pm2

Tags: node.js, deployment, pm2

I have my application written in Nodejs using Express and mongoose. I deployed it on a server using pm2 with 4 instances. However, I need to deploy it onto multiple servers. Is there a way possible with pm2?

Comment: Just wanted to know if I can do it without any Loadbalancer or not. I used google OAuth for Authentication and I mongo-store to manage the sessions.

Answer (score 2):

**Perhaps pm2 ecosystem file can do it**

You can use ecosystem file to do it,ecosystem support multi apps but just support one ssh deploy repo......

links: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/

Answer (score 1):

You can see PM2 deploy : http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/
You can specify your hosts, your ssh keys, etc...